# Unity android build crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, runtime

I am getting a crash I have trouble figuring out. The log is below. I have tried several things I read in other posts like StripEngineCode, playing with build settings. I also checked I have no preview package in my projects. Thanks for any help.

2022/04/25 14:22:02.742 20973 20997 Error CRASH *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022/04/25 14:22:02.743 20973 20973 Info ViewRootImpl@ffab79b[UnityPlayerActivity] ViewPostIme pointer 1
2022/04/25 14:22:02.743 20973 20997 Error CRASH Version '2020.3.26f1 (7298b473bc1a)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
2022/04/25 14:22:02.743 20973 20997 Error CRASH Build fingerprint: 'samsung/gts7xlwifixx/gts7xlwifi:12/SP1A.210812.016/T970XXU2CVCE:user/release-keys'
2022/04/25 14:22:02.743 20973 20997 Error CRASH Revision: '6'
2022/04/25 14:22:02.743 20973 20997 Error CRASH ABI: 'arm'
2022/04/25 14:22:02.743 20973 20997 Error CRASH Timestamp: 2022-04-25 14:22:02-0400
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH pid: 20973, tid: 20997, name: UnityMain  >>> com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent <<<
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH uid: 10785
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH Cause: null pointer dereference
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH     r0  f2a3d000  r1  00ffffe9  r2  00000001  r3  00ffffdc
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH     r4  00000000  r5  00000000  r6  00000000  r7  00310000
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH     r8  00000020  r9  0030c010  r10 f4fbf274  r11 c692d680
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH     ip  000000ff  sp  e127ae50  lr  c54c2105  pc  c60d7a02
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH backtrace:
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #00 pc 01001a02  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #01 pc 003ec103  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #02 pc 003debdd  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #03 pc 003db8dd  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.744 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #04 pc 00aa8934  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.745 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #05 pc 00cf67bb  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.745 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #06 pc 005a0a99  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.745 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #07 pc 005a19e5  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.745 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #08 pc 0059f45f  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.745 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #09 pc 00ceeacf  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.745 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #10 pc 00cf2a9f  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.745 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #11 pc 00a19610  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.745 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #12 pc 00a3173c  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.746 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #13 pc 00602783  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.746 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #14 pc 006034ff  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.746 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #15 pc 005fc3f3  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.746 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #16 pc 005fc427  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.746 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #17 pc 005fc5ed  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.746 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #18 pc 0085454d  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.747 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #19 pc 0087ce15  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.747 20973 20997 Error CRASH       #20 pc 0017d08d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (BuildId: 24f99d9b0541278f448ea3d1943c6ab1)
2022/04/25 14:22:02.778 20973 21031 Error CRASH *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022/04/25 14:22:02.778 20973 21031 Error CRASH Version '2020.3.26f1 (7298b473bc1a)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
2022/04/25 14:22:02.778 20973 21031 Error CRASH Build fingerprint: 'samsung/gts7xlwifixx/gts7xlwifi:12/SP1A.210812.016/T970XXU2CVCE:user/release-keys'
2022/04/25 14:22:02.778 20973 21031 Error CRASH Revision: '6'
2022/04/25 14:22:02.778 20973 21031 Error CRASH ABI: 'arm'
2022/04/25 14:22:02.778 20973 21031 Error CRASH Timestamp: 2022-04-25 14:22:02-0400
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH pid: 20973, tid: 21031, name: Job.Worker 0  >>> com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent <<<
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH uid: 10785
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH Cause: null pointer dereference
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH     r0  f2a3de00  r1  00ffffe9  r2  00000001  r3  00ffffdc
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH     r4  00000000  r5  00000000  r6  00000000  r7  00310000
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH     r8  00000020  r9  0030c010  r10 f4fbf274  r11 c692d680
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH     ip  000000ff  sp  b6d20c60  lr  c54c2105  pc  c60d7a02
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH backtrace:
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #00 pc 01001a02  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #01 pc 003ec103  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #02 pc 003debdd  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #03 pc 003db8dd  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #04 pc 00aa8934  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #05 pc 00cf67bb  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #06 pc 005a0a99  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #07 pc 005a0cc5  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.779 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #08 pc 005a0d41  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.780 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #09 pc 005a0eef  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.780 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #10 pc 005a062d  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.780 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #11 pc 00777533  /data/app/~~H4t_wCsjCOVnhRZhBR-YhA==/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent-p5fY9K_uIzsaKblJhDOzmA==/lib/arm/libunity.so
2022/04/25 14:22:02.780 20973 21031 Error CRASH       #12 pc 000a82a7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (pthread_attr_destroy+6) (BuildId: 8372400d8e00b0010d302309874744c2)
2022/04/25 14:22:02.916 20973 20997 Error CRASH Tombstone written to: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.DefaultCompany.HeavyDescent/files/tombstone_01

Answer (score 0):

You should give more information like your `build settings` screenshot.

Only then it will be easier to see the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by experimenting with build settings. The bug was intermittent so not 100% sure what fixed it, but switching to LL2CPP seemed to be the thing. It s working with no crash or errors in logcat since.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).